# Which approach is better in terms of performance to modify a hash, is it `Hash#merge` or double splat operator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashmap

From the below example, which approach is better in terms of performance?

```rb
h = {a: 1, b: 2}

{**h, c: 3} => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
# or 
h.merge(c: 3) => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Comment: For a Rails application, these kinds of micro-optimizations don't matter. Optimizing your code towards simplicity, readability and maintainability will have a much larger impact.

Comment: I usually use h[:c] = 3, it is work.

Comment: @Stefan which of these would you recommend to be as more readable and maintainable?

Comment: @Sathish to me, simplicity and readability means that I can quickly understand the code's intent. Without knowing why you are merging those two hashes, I'd say the second one is easier because it literally says it will `merge` `h` and `c: 3`. But there might be situations where the other one is perfectly fine. It really depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

Basic benchmarking

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.config(:time => 10, :warmup => 2)
  h = {a: 1, b: 2}
  
  x.report("splat") {{**h, c: 3}}
  x.report("merge") {h.merge(c: 3)}

  x.compare!
end
```

suggests that merge is faster, for example

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
               splat   243.017k i/100ms
               merge   315.349k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
               splat      3.388M (±11.8%) i/s -     33.293M in  10.005951s
               merge      4.721M (±12.5%) i/s -     46.356M in  10.037133s

Comparison:
               merge:  4720869.7 i/s
               splat:  3388413.3 i/s - 1.39x  (± 0.00) slower
```

Comment: You might consider adding `x.report("add key") {h.dup.tap {|g| g[:c]=3}}`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is tiny, unless you're doing millions of these operations in a tight loop.

Which one is faster depends on the "position" of the hashes. Observe:

```rb
require 'benchmark/ips'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  h = {a: 1, b: 2}.freeze
  
  # Warning: these operations don't all have the same effect due to different ordering
  x.report("splat at start") { {**h, c: 3, d: 4} }
  x.report("splat at end") { {c: 3, d: 4, **h} }
  x.report("splat at middle") { {c: 3, **h, d: 4} }
  x.report("merge literal into named") { h.merge(c: 3, d: 4) }
  x.report("merge named into literal") { {c: 3, d: 4}.merge(h) }

  x.compare!
end
puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION
```

Note: on ruby 3, you'll need to install the benchmark-ips gem.

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
      splat at start   527.143k i/100ms
        splat at end   578.550k i/100ms
     splat at middle   512.272k i/100ms
merge literal into named
                       415.284k i/100ms
merge named into literal
                       546.939k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
      splat at start      5.087M (± 3.9%) i/s -     25.830M in   5.085388s
        splat at end      5.794M (± 2.4%) i/s -     29.506M in   5.095522s
     splat at middle      5.062M (± 3.1%) i/s -     25.614M in   5.064780s
merge literal into named
                          4.139M (± 2.3%) i/s -     20.764M in   5.019108s
merge named into literal
                          5.324M (± 3.4%) i/s -     26.800M in   5.039716s

Comparison:
        splat at end:  5794056.5 i/s
merge named into literal:  5324076.5 i/s - 1.09x  slower
      splat at start:  5087349.1 i/s - 1.14x  slower
     splat at middle:  5062140.5 i/s - 1.14x  slower
merge literal into named:  4139241.2 i/s - 1.40x  slower

ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

So it seems that splats, where the splatted hash is in the final position, is the fastest.

Interestingly, "merge literal into named" was the slowest by a good margin.

Note: if you may have keys that get overwritten, you can't always position the hashes to get the best performance, because you'll get a different result.

```
[13] pry(main)> h = {c: 2}
=> {:c=>2}
[14] pry(main)> {a: 1, **h, c: 3}
=> {:a=>1, :c=>3}
[15] pry(main)> {a: 1, c: 3, **h}
=> {:a=>1, :c=>2}
```